# Get HTML values in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am kinda new to python so please cut me some slack. I have a webpage that has a specific  tag that I would like to get the value from. Is there some sort of python library I can use to get the value of that  tag? Thank you.

Comment: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/

Answer (score 1):

If it is valid xml, you can use xml.etree.ElementTree.
If not, the preferrable way to deal with html is BeautifulSoup

```
import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(your)
print soup.find('span')[0].contents
```

Something like that i believe

Comment: BeautifulSoup actually uses lxml now (optionally), and lxml can handle invalid XML!